How to write frequency on research paper?
How do I indicate a number means frequency, like "Terms Humble (f.9), Respectful(f.7),  and Inspirational (f.6) making up the most frequently used terms to describe all active Asian MLB players in the ASAP commentary database. " Is there a format to put frequency: x?
Thank you!

You could try "humble (n = 9), respectful (n = 7), etc."

What does f.9 mean?

See what the pros recommend at the Statistics stack.

I would use words rather than symbols. For example, if I understand your example correctly:

Terms Humble (9 occurrences), Respectful (7 occurrences), and Inspirational (6 occurrences) are the most frequently used terms to describe active Asian MLB players in the ASAP commentary database.

I'm not familiar with this database, but those sound like very small numbers for occurrences if the database has any reasonable size to it; I'd be careful to use language that makes clear what sort of count you are using. For example, if you mean that "humble" is mentioned for 9 different players, I would write "Humble (9 players)".
